# Resize only home page (CSS)

Tags: layout, css

How to increase width only on homepage?
If I change style.css it will affect the other ones.

Read something about `<reference>` but not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** In your CSS, filter for the class: `.cms-index-index`.

**Explanation:** Magento adds classes to the body tag based on (mostly) the url that is passed in. Here is a list of a few that may be helpful:

- `.catalog-product-view`: product page
- `.checkout-cart-index`: viewing the cart
- `.checkout-onepage-index`: onepage checkout
- `.checkout-onepage-success`: checkout success
- `.cms-page-view`: CMS page

In addition, CMS pages convert the path into a dash-based list (changing all separating characters to be hyphens), and append that to `cms-`. This would make `/about.html` to have the class `cms-about-html` and the page `/folder/file.html` to have the class `cms-folder-file.html`.